# How to count an array of dates in bootstrap multidate picker using Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap date picker that has a multidate function and I want to count the number of days selected on change but it doesn't only return the present value but also the previous value. Slicing and Trimming don't work apparently.

The Code I'm using to alert the datecount

```
$(document).on('change', '#leavedate', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const date = $('#leavedate').val();
    const datelength = date.length;
    alert(datelength);
})
```

Comment: Data output:
Selected 1 date:  Alert = 10
Selected 2 date:  Alert = 21
Selected 3 date:  Alert = 32
Selected 4 date:  Alert = 43
Selected 5 date:  Alert = 54
Selected 6 date:  Alert = 65
Selected 7 date:  Alert = 76
Selected 8 date:  Alert = 87
Selected 9 date:  Alert = 98
Selected 10 date:  Alert = 109
Selected 11 date:  Alert = 110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the javascript [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function and split the value by comma (,) then you'll get the array of dates then you can get the length of the array.

```
$(document).on('change', '#leavedate', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const date = $('#leavedate').val();
    const datelength = date != '' ? date.split(',').length : 0;
    alert(datelength);
});
```